# What prerequisites must be fulfilled so PL can get out of beta?

Tags: support

- Number of members?
- Number of questions? (total or per-day)
- Number of answers?
- Number of visitors and views?
- Complete a period of time? (six months? one year?)

Answer (score 10):

A necessary condition: at least 10 questions per day mean the site can be *considered* for graduation. [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)

But even if a [red-hot beta](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/)  gets  10 questions per day for the first several months of its existence, that doesn't automatically make it a graduation candidate. It takes a long time for a community to become large and engaged enough to support moderator elections in which more than a handful of people show up.

Excluding special projects, the youngest site to graduate is Network Engineering, which started in May 2013 and graduated in June 2015. So, I suggest revisiting this question in the middle of 2017. And chances are that by then, the [graduation policies and procedures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905) will  be different.

Comment: Thank you, Normal Human.

Comment: Most of this answer is spot-on. We'll be checking in before 2017, though. Some of the sites in the very early days of SE 2.0 (like Gaming/Arqade) actually graduated after just 90 days, back when we didn't know how things were going to work and had a lot more optimism (and low-hanging fruit available). Since then, we've seen several sites start off strong and then seem to run out of steam, so we do want to see sustained performance, but 25 months seems a little excessive for a minimum; it's probably closer to one year right now (there's no official number of days at the moment).